# Converting an Java Application to an Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am trying to convert a java application into an applet.
I had a JFrame which had a 5 JPanels on it so to convert it I made the JFrame into a JPanel (mainPanel) and made the class extend JApplet.

However, I cannot update any of the panels when the mainPanel is on the applet however with exactly the same code - when the mainPanel is on a JFrame it works and the panels update.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to choose (override) init() method to add the components.

Comment: A far better strategy is to launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh, converting a JFrame to JApplet is very easy.

Say you have a JFrame like this:

```
public class MyApp extends JFrame {
  .
  .
  public void initComponents() {
    // components initialisation here
  }
}
```

This class can easily become a JApplet:

```
public class MyApp extends JApplet {
  .
  .
  public void init() {
    // components initialisation here
  }
}
```

Note the difference - initComponents() became init() because Applets need the init() method.

Comment: *"X to JApplet is very easy."*  Anything involving 'to JApplet' is rarely, if ever, 'easy'.  Further, applets are inherently more tricky to deploy and update.  As one (of many) examples, see [Copy & Paste Not working in a *Signed* Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513740/copy-paste-not-working-in-a-signed-applet).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Java Application into Java by initializing Applet in beginning and defining components in init();