# system clipboard only inside an application

Tags: java, security, awt, clipboard

I have a swing application and I want to copy some text to the system clipboard. I do this with

```
Clipboard systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
StringSelection dataToClipboard = new StringSelection(stringToCopy);
systemClipboard.setContents(dataToClipboard, null);
```

But it exists only inside the app, I can paste it in any text field in it, but when I try to do so in a web browser, it pastes nothing.

I also tried to implement ClipboardOwner interface and pass it's reference instead of `null`, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Does *"in a web browser"* mean 'applet'?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, no, it means a web browser (Chrome)

Comment: Well what does the 'in a' mean?  The only ways I know to 'put' Java 'in a' web browser are 1) applet & 2) servlet/JSP -- but the 2nd is a red herring, since what ends up in the browser is HTML (or similar).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson raised as much as can be, the rest are unresolved problems

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I understand "try to do so in a web browser" as meaning "try to paste the text i have copied in my application into a different application (for example, a text area in a web browser)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I wrote the whole module again and this time it works.

Thank you for your time.

PS. By "in a web browser" I meant address bar in it;

Answer (score 1):

> but when I try to do so in a web browser, it pastes nothing.

Digitally sign the app., or use the equivalent JNLP API Services in a sand-box.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513818/418556) (and chase the links back to the thread at OTN) for more details.