# JNLP clipboard access (copy-paste)

Tags: java, makefile, copy-paste, jnlp

I was looking how to enable copy-paste for JNLP files. I have created policy file (like it is described here [Copy/Paste not working in a signed Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513740/copy-paste-not-working-in-a-signed-applet) or here http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/resources/InstructionsCopyPaste). But it is not working when I run `javaws application.jnlp` command.

Answer (score 0):

When I run `jnlp -verbose app.jnlp` there is interesting output, that shows what command is exactly executed. After small changes I created makefile would be like this:

```
POLICY_FILE = "${HOME}/.java.policy"
JNLP_FILE = "${HOME}/Projects/demo/application.jnlp"
SPLASH_FILE = "${HOME}/Projects/demo/splash.png"
APP_NAME = "My demo application"

default:
    "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" \
        -classpath "${JAVA_HOME}/lib/deploy.jar" \
        -Djava.security.policy="file:${POLICY_FILE}" \
        -DtrustProxy=true \
        -Xverify:remote \
        -Djnlpx.home="${JAVA_HOME}/bin" \
        -Djava.security.manager \
        -Djnlpx.origFilenameArg=${JNLP_FILE} \
        -Djnlpx.remove=false \
        -Dsun.awt.warmup=true \
        -Xbootclasspath/a:"${JAVA_HOME}/lib/javaws.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/deploy.jar":"${JAVA_HOME}/lib/plugin.jar" \
        -Xdock:name="${APP_NAME}" \
        -Dmacosx.jnlpx.dock.name="${APP_NAME}" \
        -Xdock:icon="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/deploy/webStartAppIcon.icns" \
        -Dmacosx.jnlpx.dock.icon="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/deploy/webStartAppIcon.icns" \
        -splash:"${SPLASH_FILE}" \
        -Djnlpx.jvm="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" com.sun.javaws.Main \
        -verbose \
        -notWebJava ${JNLP_FILE}
```

and `.java.policy` file:

```
grant {
  permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```